# how to click dynamic links like ads on a webpage using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium webdriver, and trying to test a webpage which has some dynamic links (dynamic ads). Example : ads on https://mail.rediff.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi

I tried with xpath ,classname and id but none of these is working.It is happening because every time new content is displaying on the page so it is not able to find the element and throwing Exception in thread "main":

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #map.
```

my code is :

```
package Selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Image_Link {

    static WebDriver driver ;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
        //driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E://geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64//geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        driver.get("https://mail.rediff.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi");
        //WebElement Dynamic_ads=driver.findElement(By.className("rhs-area floatR"));
        WebElement Dynamic_ads=driver.findElement(By.id("map"));
        actions.moveToElement(Dynamic_ads).perform();
        WebElement ad_Link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#map > area:nth-child(2)"));
        actions.moveToElement(ad_Link);
        actions.click();
        actions.perform();

        //driver.navigate().to("www.google.com");

        //String value = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo")).getAttribute("title");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements for the dynamic ads cannot be found because it isn't fully loaded yet on load page. I recommend adding an explicit wait time for the specific add you're looking for. You can check out this [link](https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html) here for more information.

Anyhow, here's your solution:

1.)Implement WebDriverWait: `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);`

2.) Change your `Dynamic_ads` data to `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("map")));` then do `Dynamic_ads.click();` afterwards.

OR

2.) Change your `Dynamic_ads` data to `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//map[@id='map']/*")));` then do `Dynamic_ads.click();` afterwards. NOTE: This will pick the first child node.

Comment: Thank you for your help....But every time when the browser is opened (manually or by selenium), a different  set of ads is showing...hence that particular element is not visible on the page.And I want to verify that ads shown on the page are clickable (for example : rediff login page).

Comment: If you want to verify that ads shown on the page are clickable, doing the same thing but slightly modifying Step 2 to:

 `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//map[@id='map']/*"))); then do Dynamic_ads.click();` 


NOTE: the element that would chosen is going to be the first child element of the map.

Comment: I have tried above line of code but same error is showing "No such element".Although I tried to find out the element which is constant even when a new browser is opened.                                                                        //identify advertisement area                                                         
 WebElement Dynamic_ads= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("advertisement-area"))); Dynamic_ads.click();

Comment: You added an explicit wait time as well? So that the element will have enough time to load?

Comment: Yes,I also tried with   WebElement Dynamic_ads= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("advertisement-area"))); 
Dynamic_ads.click();     since whole advertisement area is clickable,it is now going to rediff shopping site.But I want to click a particular product link shown  on login page.I found out that whenever new browser is opened,irrespective of the ad loaded on that page,cssSelector for child node 1,2 etc of image map will remain same as " #map > area:nth-child(1)" ," #map > area:nth-child(2)" etc. But when I am using it ,facing same problem